# IIS7 - Shared Configuration stored on a File cluster

Tags: iis-7, configuration, share

We have two webservers, running IIS7 and using Shared Configuration to store their configuration data on a redundant file cluster.

This normally works fine, however, when the primary machine in the file cluster is rebooted, we get the following error:

> The Windows Process Activation Service encountered an error trying to
>   read configuration data from file
>   '\fileClusterName\Files\IISSharedConfig\applicationHost.config',
>   line number '0'. The error message is: 'Cannot read configuration file
>   because the network path is not found

Looking at c:\inetpub\temp\appPools\ we see that a number of the files in here are just a couple of KB, and contain this error message instead of a local cache of the configuration (which is what they contain when all is working normally).

This error is not temporary, but persists, bringing down the application pools and thus websites, until we delete the dodgy files in c:\inetpub\temp\appPools and restart IIS.

Can anyone suggest what we might be doing wrong, and what can be done to fix it.

Comment: Is this 2008, or R2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this IIS forum link.  Sounds similar to your issue you may need to cache the config.

http://forums.iis.net/t/1149683.aspx

Comment: Yes - thanks, this was the case. We solved it by setting up local caching of the configs.